# SVG Sprites with <use> and xlink:href

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am using SVG spriting which seems to be working really well, well so I thought until I opened the site in ie9(our minimum supported browser). All SVG's were not displaying. heres how I was referencing my SVG's:

```
<svg class="icon-search">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-search"></use>
</svg>
```

So this works in all modern browsers but after some research this is now deprecated and you should just use href without the xlink:. So I changed all my SVG's to look like this:

```
<svg class="icon-search">
    <use href="#icon-search"></use>
</svg>
```

Now my problem is that my SVG's do not work in Safari and ios!! im looking for a solution that will work for all modern browsers and down to IE9. Has anyone come across this problem and found a good solution?

Comment: if you add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` as attribute to the `<svg>` and keep `xlink:href=""` ??

Comment: **xlink** namespace is not depricated. See [XML Linking Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/) specification. If you use [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) then you need to definition **xlink** namespace prefix before use one.

Comment: Just given this a go but no luck. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: update: If i use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" on the <use> tag this seems to do the trick

Comment: The `xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"` declaration is **not** needed for inline SVG. The browser is already aware of that namespace.  It is only required for external/standalone SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use polyfill [svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody)

Answer (score 0):

Supply both attributes. Modern browsers will prefer href over xlink:href.

I don't think modern browsers will drop support for xlink:href till Safari implements it. I opposed removing xlink:href support from Firefox for that reason.